# iphone - launching an app and loading a file

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have built my own URL scheme for my App.

As far as I understand, now I can have a link on a email, in the form

myApp://....

and my app will launch.

But what I need is this:

1. my app creates its own kind of files. It is a zip file renamed as AnyName.myApp
2. I need this app to allow the user to mail this file to another person that uses my App.
3. This person must be able to tap on the attachment and open the attachment with my app.

How do I do that?

Can you guys point me in the right direction or give me some code to start?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [iOS 4 Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW12) for details.

Comment: And keep in mind, the ability to register your app as a specific file handler is only available in iOS4 or higher

Comment: Starting from iPhone OS 3.2 on iPad, more precisely.